# How do I make a .net Assembly visible

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've made a class library that's COM visible - but I can't add a reference to it via COM>Type Libraries - instead it tells me "add a reference to the .net assembly instead" which is all fine and dandy, but I can't find the assembly in the list (even though it's visible in COM type libraries)

Now - I know I can just add a reference to the entire project and start instancing my classes, but I don't really want to. I don't want the extra project in there with the ability to start changing stuff in that referenced project.

I would just like to add a reference to its assembly name - can I do this or does it always have to be via project addition?! If it is via project-addition only then can I completely lock that project since it's a reference project?

Comment: I suppose it requires some kind of registration? Check Regasm.exe

Comment: I've already installed it too, via an msi installer package - I thought that would handle the lot because when deploying this library to other computers this way it seems they can reference it in applications (like VBA etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

1. Simply reference a DLL built from your project. You can for instance copy a DLL to a project-local folder in your target project, and reference that.
2. Install the DLL to be referenced in the GAC. It needs to have a strong name, which is recommended anyway, and this needs to be repeated for every new version of the DLL, as the GAC retains a copy of the file, unlike the COM registry, which only references the library and typelib.

A reference only by assembly name is not possible, as the compiler needs to know details about the containing classes of the target assembly in order to run the build process.

Referencing an assembly via COM does completely different things, i.e. the resolving runs through CreateInstance, which searches the registry for the class GUID and might even return a proxy to a remote host.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to properties --> build --> Check 'Register for COM Interop'. That will sign and register your class libraries as a qualified Interop COM DLL in your machine. You might have missed it

Comment: Typelibs for COM visible classes from a .NET assembly cannot be added to a .NET project anyway.

Comment: Oh yes! I was thinking that the question was related to discovering the class library in other console refs as COM.